# Ignore Jars INDEX.LIST with java webstart

Tags: java, java-web-start

We have a third party jar which has an INDEX.LIST file contained in META-INF. This causes java web start to request the jars listed in INDEX.LIST

Our server only responds to jar requests that are versioned and when java webstart requests jars it finds in the INDEX.LIST file it doesn't include the version.

What would work for us is to simply turn off the Jar Indexing support but I have not seen any documentation on how to turn this feature off.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, and currently, I just delete the **INDEX.LIST** from jar.

Comment: We have done the same but we customized our gradle build to remove all INDEX.LIST files from any JAR which is used with webstart. This does not work for already signed JARs, but we did not yet encuonter that problem.